# ppolicy with pam_ldap - pwdReset has no effect when logging in from Ubuntu

Tags: ldap, authentication, openldap, pam-ldap, password-policy

We installed ppolicy overlay on our ldap server. Password policies work correctly for locking out user after X incorrect password attempts, but we can't enforce user to change his password.

When we set pwdReset=TRUE attribute for a user - user can login as usual from Ubuntu client machine.

Ldap server & client were setup according to Ubuntu howto: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/openldap-server.html

Client machine uses pam_ldap

Configuration file /etc/ldap.conf has "pam_lookup_policy yes" line

But pwdReset attribute is ignored.

According to what I read on the internet pam_ldap should honor ppolicy and require user to change his password when pwdReset is set. But it doesn't work for us..

How to make ubuntu client honor pwdReset attribute?

Maybe I can turn on debug logging for pam_ldap? But I can't find how to do it...

Answer (score 2):

You must make sure that `pwdMustChange` is set to `TRUE` on the user's effective password policy.

See [the slapo-ppolicy manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/slapo-ppolicy) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this as well -- my particular problem was that while some third-party applications (Okta in our case) looks for `pwdReset`, the `pam_ldap` plugin does not.

After taking a look at the source code for `pam_ldap` as hosted here: https://github.com/wfhu/pam_ldap -- I've come to the conclusion that `pam_ldap` completely ignores `pwdReset` which is part of OpenLDAP's `ppolicy.schema`. You can find the schema that OpenLDAP uses here: http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ape/ppolicy.html

NOTE: I believe the problem is that the OpenLDAP policy attributes are different from the original schema that (Netscape?/UniversityOfMichigan?/Sun?) LDAP server implementation used, which is what `pam_ldap` expects.

What **does** work correctly is the `shadow*` attributes that are part of the `shadowAccount` objectClass.

[Steps are for Ubuntu]

1. Make sure that your user(s) have a password policy set in LDAP by checking `pwdPolicySubentry`:

   ```
   ldapsearch (...) -b dc=example,dc=org "(uid=testinguser)" pwdPolicySubentry
   ```
2. Check your user's `shadow*` information

   ```
   slapcat -a uid=testinguser
   ```
3. Set `shadowLastChange` to 0 to allow `pam_ldap` to recognise an expired password

   This could be done via a script that checks for `pwdReset` and updates `shadowLastChange`.

When this is setup PAM will correctly force a user to change their password on login.

See also:
http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201210/msg00044.html